# Moving /var from LVM to a non-LVM disk

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I inherited an LVM based centos setup where root is at an LVM partiton. I want to move my /var to a new harddisk without adding it to the LVM group. Is it possible to mount the new harddisk to /var without adding it to the LVM, like adding it to fstab directly?

Comment: Curious why you want to do this - is it because /var files are causing the root LV to fill up?  Generally in a root-on-LVM setup you might as well put /var on another LV.  If you have lots of your own files under /var (e.g. /var/home/ directories), it would be better to put them on a separate 'home' LVM probably.

Comment: /var contained a lot of small files which was causing slow disk i/o, i wanted to speed it up using an SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is **certainly** doable **offline**. LVM **certainly** makes it easy to do the data move **online**, but depending on your situation you **may** be able to do it **online** even **without** LVM.

The online and offline process is essentially the same when not using LVM.

## Offline operation

If you are okay with taking the machine offline for a while, I would recommend booting from a live media (I would recommend [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/)), then prepare the disk for the new `/var` partition (partition it and prepare a file system for it), mount both the LVM based `/var` and the newly formatted `/var`, and then copy all the data from the one disk to the other (`rsync` is my recommendation here).

You would then have to update your `/etc/fstab` and you are set.

If you do not want to boot in a live media, you may have some luck booting in single user mode. Or, you can just bite the bullet and try to do it online.

## Online operation

The procedure when moving the data **online** is pretty much the same as the offline procedure, but you have to additionally be very careful about any processes that use the old `/var` partition. If there is nothing critical on it, you don't have to be so careful, and a final reboot will take care of the leftovers.

The procedure

1. Partition the new disk and prepare the new filesystem
2. Mount the `/var`-to-be filesystem somewhere (I will assume `/mnt/newvar` for simplicity)
3. Copy all files from `/var` to `/mnt/newvar` (`rsync -avHPSAX /var/ /mnt/newvar/`)
4. Check what processes hold any open files in `/var` and stop them (`lsof -n / | awk '$9 ~ /^\/var\//'` will let you know)
5. sync the disks again (`rsync -avHP --delete /var/ /mnt/newvar/`). This should be fast as there will hardly be any updates
6. When you are sure that nothing is writing to `/var`, umount `/mnt/newvar` and mount it on `/var`
7. Update `/etc/fstab`
8. Reboot
9. After the reboot you can delete the volume that used to be `/var`. If your `/var` was not a separate volume and is just part of `/`, then you can `mount -o bind / /mnt`, and clean up `/mnt/var` (remember to keep `/mnt/var` as it is the mountpoint).

If you need more details, you would have to short more information about your setup, like the output of `df -hTP /var`, `lvm lvs`, and `fdisk -l` for the new disk that you want to use.

Comment: I don't have access to the server other than ssh, so i need to do it live. I don't mind going offline, but i need to do it without booting with live media

Comment: @Tutul, I updated the answer with online help.